# Why I'm getting those erros on my mongoose pre schema?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I'm migrating a existing project to typescript, it's a Yelp Camp clone and my camground schame is:

```
import { Schema, model, Document } from "mongoose";

import Comments, {IComment} from "./comments"

export interface ICampground extends Document {
  name: string;
  image: string;
  description: string;
  comments?: IComment[];
  author: {
    id: string;
    username: string;
  };
  price: string;
  location: string;
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
  createdAt?: Date;
}

const campgroundSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  image: String,
  imageId: String,
  description: String,
  comments: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Comment",
    },
  ],
  author: {
    id: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
    username: String,
  },
  price: String,
  location: String,
  lat: Number,
  lng: Number,
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

campgroundSchema.pre("remove", async () => {
  await Comments.remove({
    _id: {
      $in: this.comments,
    },
  });

});

export default model<ICampground>("Campground", campgroundSchema);
```

However I'm getting these errors:

1. `The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this'`
2. `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature`

On this part of the code:

```
campgroundSchema.pre("remove", async () => {
  await Comments.remove({
    _id: {
      $in: this.comments,
    },
  });
});
```

More details:

1 - This "this" keyword references the CampgroundModel, so is not possible to use normal functions because CommentsModel don't have "comments"...

Some doubts:

1 - There's another way to remove all related Comments when I delete one campground?

2 - Also, typescript complain about comments non existence on this, how can I "set" this "this" to the CampgroundModel?

Comment: What happens if you replace your arrow function with `async function(this: CampgroundModel) { /* ... */ }`?

Comment: Oh, this worked like a charm! I didn't know I could set the "this" keyword types! Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! I made it an answer so that others can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell TypeScript what should `this` be when a function is invoked:

```
campgroundSchema.pre("remove", async function(this: ICampground) => {
  await Comments.remove({
    _id: {
      $in: this.comments,
    },
  });
```

Comment: So, I'm exporting the CampgroundModel so, the type of this is ICampground, that is my custom inteface that extends mongoose.Document.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you.